# Sort Array Index by SubArray Value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I've got the following structue of array, but i need sort by mark value and on duplicated need sort at last by array index:

this is my Array base `$AsocContData[$s_list_100]`:

```
array(5) {
    [01081] => Array(3){
        [id] => 2
        [Mark] => 420
        [lastUpdated] => 2010-03-17 15:44:12
        [dataNext] => Array(2){
            [more1] => 54
            [More2] => 54
        }
    }
    [00358] => Array(3){
        [id] => 6
        [Mark] => 500
        [lastUpdated] => 2010-03-17 15:44:12
        [dataNext] => Array(2){
            [more1] => 54
            [More2] => 54
        }
    }
    [00277] => Array(3){
        [id] => 3
        [Mark] => 400
        [lastUpdated] => 2010-03-17 15:44:12
        [dataNext] => Array(2){
            [more1] => 54
            [More2] => 54
        }
    }
    [00357] => Array(3){
        [id] => 1
        [Mark] => 500
        [lastUpdated] => 2010-03-17 15:44:12
        [dataNext] => Array(2){
            [more1] => 54
            [More2] => 54
        }
    }
}
```

What's the best way for order the array by sub-array and on duplicated use the Index array, incremental?

So the results look like this:

```
array(5) {
    [00277] => Array(3){
        [id] => 3
        [Mark] => 400
        [lastUpdated] => 2010-03-17 15:44:12
        [dataNext] => Array(2){
            [more1] => 54
            [More2] => 54
        }
    }
    [01081] => Array(3){
        [id] => 2
        [Mark] => 420
        [lastUpdated] => 2010-03-17 15:44:12
        [dataNext] => Array(2){
            [more1] => 54
            [More2] => 54
        }
    }
    [00357] => Array(3){
        [id] => 1
        [Mark] => 500
        [lastUpdated] => 2010-03-17 15:44:12
        [dataNext] => Array(2){
            [more1] => 54
            [More2] => 54
        }
    }
    [00358] => Array(3){
        [id] => 6
        [Mark] => 500
        [lastUpdated] => 2010-03-17 15:44:12
        [dataNext] => Array(2){
            [more1] => 54
            [More2] => 54
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**

I try to use this, but it does not have the desired scope with php 7.2:

```
usort($AsocContData[$s_list_100], function ($a, $b) {
    return $a['Prod_Mark'] <=> $b['Prod_Mark'];
});
```

this return and not sort for duplicates:

```
array(20) {
  [0]=>// remplace this first Index array with position and it is a fail.
  array(38) {

  }
}
```

**Update**

the base array is dynamic nested, and can have much more Array child nested.

Comment: Show us what you've tried, and we can help with errors you're having.

Comment: Write your own comparison function and call it with `usort` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Comment: @miken32 i have update the post; adding first funtion i have used to sort the array , but the problem is that replace the index array that is associative and i dont know the result in case of duplicated mark... the error is around logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use [`array_multisort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)

```
array_multisort(
    array_column( $AsocContData[$s_list_100], 'Mark' ), // sort by the Mark sub-array value first
    SORT_ASC, // ascending
    SORT_NUMERIC, // treat data as numeric
    array_keys( $AsocContData[$s_list_100] ), // secondly, sort by the array indexes
    SORT_ASC, // ascending
    SORT_NUMERIC, // treat indexes as numeric
    $AsocContData[$s_list_100] // this array will be sorted in place and by reference
);

var_dump( $AsocContData[$s_list_100] );
```

Input:

```
$AsocContData[$s_list_100] = array(
    '01081' => Array(
        'id' => 2,
        'Mark' => 420,
        'lastUpdated' => '2010-03-17 15:44:12'
    ),
    '00358' => Array(
        'id' => 6,
        'Mark' => 500,
        'lastUpdated' => '2010-03-17 15:44:12'
    ),
    '00277' => Array(
        'id' => 3,
        'Mark' => 400,
        'lastUpdated' => '2010-03-17 15:44:12'
    ),
    '00357' => Array(
        'id' => 1,
        'Mark' => 500,
        'lastUpdated' => '2010-03-17 15:44:12'
    )
);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [00277] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [Mark] => 400
            [lastUpdated] => 2010-03-17 15:44:12
        )

    [01081] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [Mark] => 420
            [lastUpdated] => 2010-03-17 15:44:12
        )

    [00357] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [Mark] => 500
            [lastUpdated] => 2010-03-17 15:44:12
        )

    [00358] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [Mark] => 500
            [lastUpdated] => 2010-03-17 15:44:12
        )

)
```

Comment: thank and yes i missed add full array structure; it is a multidimensional array. that is dinamic Nested and can have much more childs array.

Comment: @walternuñez oh okay, so what is your sorting criteria? Is `more1` or `More2` important?

Comment: not, i find the issues is becouse the example data colum name is Mark and in my Array Production server is Prod_Mark. Lol thank you

Comment: @walternuñez I see, well I'm glad you got it figured out.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$list = [
    277 => [
        'id' => 3,
        'Mark' => 400,
        'lastUpdated' => '2010-03-17 15:44:12'
    ],
    1081 => [
        'id' => 2,
        'Mark' => 420,
        'lastUpdated' => '2010-03-17 15:44:12'
    ],
    357 => [
        'id' => 1,
        'Mark' => 500,
        'lastUpdated' => '2010-03-17 15:44:12'
    ],
    358 => [
        'id' => 6,
        'Mark' => 500,
        'lastUpdated' => '2010-03-17 15:44:12'
    ]
];

$tmp = array_column($list, 'Mark');
array_multisort($tmp, SORT_ASC, array_keys($list), SORT_ASC, $list);
var_dump($list);
```

Should do it

Comment: array_multisort(): Array sizes are inconsistent

Comment: That isn't possible unless your data isn't how you say it is, I'll update my answer with the full code which I tested

Comment: thank and yes i missed add full array structure; it is a multidimensional array. that is dinamic Nested and can have much more childs array.

Comment: not, i find the issues is becouse the example data colum name is Mark and in my Array Production server is Prod_Mark. Lol thank you